# How can i hide my facebook application activities?

Tags: facebook, hide

I do not want my app users to know who else uses the application. Can i hide it so that it doesn't show in the search and can only be accessed with invitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option in the application settings that is called "Social Discovery".  Set it to "Off".  The application also won't show up in the search if you haven't opted to adding it to the search.  However if you the app installed, it will show up in the search for you.